# How to implement PayPal IPN Listener in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am trying to implement the IPN Listener like I understand from this instruction:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/ipn/IPNImplementation/

```
    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // support encoded bodies
app.post("/paypal_me", function(req,res) {
    var VERIFY_URL_PROD = "https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
    var VERIFY_URL_TEST = "https://ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
    res.sendStatus(200); //ELSE PAYPAL WILL RESEND

    request.post({
            'content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'user-agent': 'NodeJS-IPN-Verification-Script',
            url:     VERIFY_URL_TEST,
            body:    "cmd=_notify-validate&"+req.body
    }, function(error,response,body){
        console.log(response);
        //INVALID/VERIFIED
    });
});
```

But paypal sends me events twice, which means he didn't receive Status 200 properly, and also the response is INVALID.
Am I doing something wrong with the request.post() ?

Comment: for what I know about `Request` your body is not correct because `req.body` is not a string, it's an object (a simple console.log) will prove that. In the first Google Search page, there's something about IPN with NodeJs that I think [it might help you](https://medium.com/@danielsternlicht/handling-paypal-ipn-messages-with-nodejs-5ccd97870c4)

Comment: JSON.stringify(req.body); should do the job I guess then. The article pretty much iterates the keys and values and adds them to a string.

Comment: that won't work either... you should really check the `Request` documentation, can't be that hard, can it?  will work with Axios though... and you need to attach your extra as `req.body.cmd = '_notify-validate'`